# Any way to mark a field as "ignore" for IConfiguration Get<T>?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Or a better way to ask, is it possible to mix settings from IConfiguration in a destination class slong with other fields that shouldn't be loaded (in my example, ConcurrentQueue QueuedItems?

```
public class GeorgeClass
{
    public string SourceName { get; set;} = string. Empty;
    public int MaxIterations { get; set;} = 0;
    // to be ignored. Attribute? Or if I change set to init? Enquiring minds want to know.
    public ConcurrentQueue<FredClass> QueuedItems {get; set;} = new();
    public string[] IgnoreBobs {get; set;} = new Array.Empty<string>();
}

public class FredClass
{
    public bool IsThis {get; set;} = true;
    public bool IsThat {get; set;} = false;
    public int SomeInteger {get; set;} = 15;
    public string OtherStuff {get; set;} = "Other settings, classes, arrays, etc";
}

// Somewhere constructor somewhere. config is injected IConfiguration.
public class ClassThatUSesSettings
var settings = config.GetSection("The:Section").Get<GeorgeClass[]>();
```

I've tried to search for this, but either I'm not using the correct search terms, or it doesn't exist. Could it also be considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: If needed, this is under .net-core 6.0

Comment: You can edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74307221/edit and add additional info there directly if you want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to have read-only properties that are not specified in configuration JSON files, or methods, or have the class inherit from other class, or have the configuration class implement an interface, etc.

All that is possible.

It is even possible to have data injected by services or other pieces of configuration sections by using an implementation of the [IPostConfigureOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ipostconfigureoptions-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) interface.  For example, this is the first blog/tutorial I see in the Google results:  [Simplifying dependency injection for IConfigureOptions with the ConfigureOptions()](https://andrewlock.net/simplifying-dependency-injection-for-iconfigureoptions-with-the-configureoptions-helper/).

Comment: That article (and some others referenced by it) makes the most sense. However, my particular case one of the objects doesn't have a parameterless constructor, so I moved the settings to a class and referenced that as a field in the original class.  Thanks very much for the reference.